# Adding a delay to a jQuery AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 input boxes: 'Title' and 'URL'.

'Title' uses the `onblur` event to call the function `GetURL()` and 'URL' uses the `onkeyup` event to call the function `GetURL()`.

The `GetURL()` function does some checking of the input contents then calls uses AJAX to return a formatted string.

The function is shown below, but how to I add a delay so that if the user is typing fast, the function isn't called repeatedly?

```
<input type="text" id="Title" name="Title" onblur="GetURL('Title');">
<input type="text" id="URL" name="URL" onkeyup="GetURL('URL');">

function GetURL(strFieldID) {
    if (strFieldID=="Title"&&$('#URL').val()!="") {
        //do nothing
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_dataprovider_url.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {URL: $('#'+strFieldID).val()},
            async: false,
            cache: false
        }).done(function(strResponse) {
            //output the formatted URL
            document.getElementById("PageURL").value = strResponse;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: setTimeout() as delay, and abort() to kill pending requests from the old string? The basic tools are there ready to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a variable to delay stop sending simultaneously.

```
var sending=false;
function GetURL(strFieldID) {
if (strFieldID=="Title"&&$('#URL').val()!="") {
    //do nothing
}
else if (!sending) {
    sending=true;
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_dataprovider_url.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {URL: $('#'+strFieldID).val()},
        async: false,
        cache: false
    }).done(function(strResponse) {
        //output the formatted URL
        sending=false;
        document.getElementById("PageURL").value = strResponse;
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna answer my own question...

```
function GetURL(strFieldID) {
if (strFieldID=="Title"&&$('#URL').val()!="") {
    //do nothing
}
else {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_dataprovider_url.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {URL: $('#'+strFieldID).val()},
            async: false,
            cache: false
        }).done(function(strResponse) {
            //output the formatted URL
            document.getElementById("PageURL").value = strResponse;
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

I told you it was simple!